# How to switch between MySQL 5.7 and 8.0

Tags: mysql

The current version of MySQL on my workstation is 8.0, but for other development purposes I need to switch to 5.7. My machine is running Windows 7 Enterprise 64-bit.

What is the most painless way for me to switch back and forth between the two versions?

Comment: If your using MYSQL 8.0 only features or you are using features that were retired, you don’t, you need to pick one and stick with it.

Comment: Install second MySQL instance into another folder from .ZIP source archive. Edit its my.ini and separate the instances fully (source dir, basedir, listening port, service name, pipe name, etc...). To switch between versions use proper port number or pipe name for to connect. Alternatively - store the same port/pipename, start the service you need following stop another version service. Alternatively - install VMM and install secondary version into it (or both versions - to separate VMs), switch by change MySQL server IP address.